# Setspace consistency along varying font sizes

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

Is there a way to get `\setspace` to work for the font size specified? In my MWE below you can see that when I use `tiny` the double spacing is the same as it would be for the default font. However, I want the double spacing to be `tiny` double spacing, not `normalsize` double spacing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{2}

    \blindtext[1]

    \begin{tiny}
        \blindtext[2]
    \end{tiny}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this must be a duplicate, I'll find but you are misusing the size change command, leave a blank line before `\end{tiny}`

Comment: Note that `\setstretch{2}` might not be correct double spacing. For that use `\doublespacing`. You'll notice the difference.

Comment: skillmoin- I'm actually using 1.5 spacing in my actual project, so `\doublespacing` wouldn't do

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that fixed the problem. Thanks!